# How to connect points with curved and smooth lines

Tags: r, plot, line, smoothing

I have the `ctlns` list and I am trying to produce some visualization of the data

```
ctlns<-list(structure(list(level = 10, x = c(0.101666666666667, 0.06, 
0.0385714285714286, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.04, 0.0433333333333333, 
0.05, 0.0516666666666667, 0.06, 0.0606416584402764, 0.0606416584402764, 
0.0766666666666667, 0.0766666666666667, 0.0933333333333333, 0.0933333333333333, 
0.0975, 0.11, 0.110956351152526, 0.110956351152526, 0.135, 0.135
), y = c(0.01, 0.04125, 0.06, 0.11, 0.16, 0.21, 0.26, 0.31, 0.36, 
0.41, 0.458123195380173, 0.46, 0.51, 0.56, 0.61, 0.66, 0.71, 
0.76, 0.808123195380173, 0.81, 0.86, 0.91, 0.96)), .Names = c("level", 
"x", "y")))
```

Then I,

```
 plot(ctlns[[1]]$x,ctlns[[1]]$y, xlim=c(0,.21), ylim=c(0,1), lwd=2, type="l", col="darkred" )
```

And I get the plot 
[image]

I would like to smooth the upper part of the red curve (y>0.2) while maintaining some of the curved structure  (y<0.2)

```
lines(lowess(ctlns[[1]]$x,ctlns[[1]]$y,f=2/3), lwd=2, col="darkblue")
```

does a fine job for the former part but deletes the lower part of the curve. I have the following questions:

1. Why does this happen that?
2. How can I preserve and smooth the lower part of the red curve? Or maybe combine curves/smooth lines?
3. Ignoring the red curve, how can I instruct lowess based on the blue curve data to extrapolate the values till y=0?

**EDIT after discussion with agstudy**

Because of of the curved nature of the red line, I was thinking what I need is probably a **not** a function smoothing `y~x` but rather a **graph** function that connects the points `x, y` with some kind of curved line. The points should be connected in order they appear within their vectors (`x[1]` with `y[1]` and so on...)

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: Does lowess even work for double-valued functions?  I'd be surprised if it did.  Try swapping `$x` and `$y` , doing the fit, and then swapping back if desired.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more?

Comment: Well, do you know the definition of a function, and surjective/injective types?  Take a look at the wikipedia page.  My point is that, for your data, `y=f(x)` is not single-valued, while `x=g(y)` is.

Comment: You are correct. Please see revised edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to use the `xspline` function (or `grid.xspline` if using grid graphics).

```
plot( ctlns[[1]], type='l', col='red' )
xspline( ctlns[[1]], shape=1, border='blue' )
```

You can do some pre smoothing of the data which might help some as well:

```
tmp.x <- ctlns[[1]]$x
tmp.y <- ctlns[[1]]$y

tmp <- cumsum( c(TRUE, head(tmp.x,-1) != tail(tmp.x,-1) ) )

tmp2.x <- tapply( tmp.x, tmp, mean )
tmp2.y <- tapply( tmp.y, tmp, mean )

xspline( tmp2.x, tmp2.y, shape=1, border='green' )
```

or using loess for the smoothing:

```
fit <- loess( tmp.y ~ tmp.x+tmp )
tmp3.y <- tapply( fitted(fit), tmp, mean )
xspline( tmp2.x, tmp3.y, shape=1, border='orange' )
```

Comment: This is fantastic! Thanks a lot. Is there any way to smooth the upper part (y>0.2) a bit more as to resemble a straight line?

Comment: @ECII, not easily using just `xspline`.  I tried values of `shape` greater than 1 and some did smooth it a bit more, but there were also strange artifacts doing that (and the documentation says to only use values between -1 and 1).  You can presmooth the data, see my edits above for one possibility.

Comment: Great. Thank you very much. Its exactly what I need. Do you mind explaining a bit your pre smoothing?

Comment: The `tmp` vector just captures when x values that are next to each other in the vector also have the same value.  So we just take the mean of the y-values for duplicated x's (but only neighboring duplicates).

Answer (score 2):

to answer part 2 of your question:

```
lines(lowess(ctlns[[1]]$x[ctlns[[1]]$y<0.2],
            ctlns[[1]]$y[ctlns[[1]]$y<0.2]), lwd=2, col="darkblue")
```

For the first part of your question , I guess that the algorithm is designed to work on function (mathematical defintion of the term) it removes the duplicates on x.

**Edit** after OP comment!

for me this is good , at least that I use LOESS function in an optimal manner.
If you want to join all parts you create a small line for points that create problem.

```
 ids <- duplicated(ctlns[[1]]$x) & ctlns[[1]]$y < 0.25
 lines(ctlns[[1]]$x[ids],ctlns[[1]]$y[ids], lwd=4, col="darkblue")
```

[image]

Comment: dude, you have to check your answers before submitting. Your revised answer still does not work (problems with syntax)

Comment: Sorry for being bit harse but this looks bad      `plot(ctlns[[1]]$x,ctlns[[1]]$y, xlim=c(0,.21), ylim=c(0,1), lwd=2, col="darkred" );lines(lowess(ctlns[[1]]$x,ctlns[[1]]$y,f=2/3), lwd=2, col="darkblue");lines(lowess(ctlns[[1]]$x[ctlns[[1]]$y<0.2],           ctlns[[1]]$y[ctlns[[1]]$y<0.2]), lwd=2, col="darkblue");ids <- duplicated(ctlns[[1]]$x) & ctlns[[1]]$y < 0.25;
lines(ctlns[[1]]$x[ids],ctlns[[1]]$y[ids], lwd=4, col="darkblue")`

Comment: No no problem .But looks bad is subjective, isn'it?

Comment: Bad is subjective. But I think you understand what I am looking for. Anyway thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: Really I don't understand. Maybe it will be more clear when others post better solutions.